# Shell script start 1 session with multiple windows

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-screen

I am pretty new to shell scripting (you may say I am just starting).
What I need is to write a shell script to open ONLY 1 "screen" session. Then I want to open multiple windows (say 10) in the same session and have each session to do something e.g print "hello".
So here is a part of my code but it only creates one window (0) and doesn't print anything on that window:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen-d -m -S mysession
for n in {1..10}; do
    i=$(($n-1))
    screen -S mysession -p $i -X echo "hello"
done
```

Like I said, my sample code doesn't work! It opens one session with only one window '0', and there is nothing printed on the terminal on window '0'.

Could you please give me some help? The code is supposed to open one screen session and then in the loop to open 10 windows and print "hello" in each window.

Thank you in advance!

Abedin

Comment: What do you mean by "window"?  Is that a `screen`-specific term?  You may want to tag your question with `screen` rather than `shell`.

Comment: I am so sorry for the wrong tag guys! I am pretty new to StackOverflow as well. I'll keep the comment in mind for future posts!

Answer (score 12):

The command you can send with `-X` option is not shell command but screen command.

Check CUSTOMIZATION section in `man screen` to see the list of screen command.
the following code uses `screen` command to create new window and `stuff` command to show text on the window.

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -d -m -S mysession
# window 0 is created by default, show hello0 on it
screen -S mysession -p 0 -X stuff hello0
for n in {1..9}; do
  # create now window using `screen` command
  screen -S mysession -X screen $n
  screen -S mysession -p $n -X stuff hello$n
done
```

Now you can attach to `myscreen` session and check that there are 10 windows and hello0 .. hello9 is displayed in each window.

```
$ screen -r mysession
[Press C-a "]
```

Comment: If you want to run a command, a good idiom (from devstack) is to have a newline variable (`NL=\`echo -ne '\015'\``) and append that to your command, like so: `screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff "ping en.wikipedia.org$NL"`