# Automate creating Unix screen and running multiple commands in multiple windows

Tags: shell, unix, gnu-screen

I need to run multiple servers in a `VM(Ubuntu 14.04)`. I'm using screen to do this. Now, every time I bring the VM down, I have to start the screens again. So, I'm writing a shell script to automate this. Following is my script as of now

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Create a screen in detached mode and set default title
screen -d -m -S screenName -t "DjangoServer"
# Start django app in window 0
# Source environment variables for screen shell.
# TODO: Check if this is required.
screen -S screenName -X stuff $"source ~/.profile\n"
# Start virtual environment(virt_env command) exported via ~/.profile 
screen -S screenName -X stuff $"virt_env\n"
# Run Django app using grunt
screen -S screenName -X stuff $"grunt\n"
# Start node app in window 1
screen -S screenName -X screen -t "NodeAPI"
screen -S screenName -p 1 -X stuff $"cd /vagrant/node-app\n"
screen -S screenName -p 1 -X stuff $"npm start\n"
# Start a screen running a shell, simply
screen -S screenName -X screen -t "bash"
```

I am new to shell scripting and am sure there must be a better way to do this. Could anyone tell me how to. Since the commands are very few, I'm not inclined towards writing a shell scripts for the commands to be run in screen-windows. But if that is the standard way, do suggest how to. TIA.

EDIT

I don't want to modify `.screenrc` as well.

Comment: Please, search. It took just few seconds. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74785/how-to-open-tabs-windows-in-gnu-screen-execute-commands-within-each-one

Comment: I had gone through the link you have posted above. And part of my try is influenced from the approach there. I don't want to alter ```.screenrc```. I forgot to mention that. But yes I did spend good 2 hrs searching about it. Hope it satisfies your altruism now :D

Comment: Why do you not want to modify `.screenrc`? That is the best way to accomplish what you are trying to do. Would creating additional config files so that you can run `screen -c some-other-screenrc` be acceptable (note those config files can include your main `.screenrc` via `source ...`)?

Comment: I don't want to modify ```.screenrc``` only because I think, maybe because I don't fully understand, there could be a better way to do that. Everytime on every machine that we need to do something of this sort, modifying ```.screenrc``` in VM doesn't sound good to me. Moreover, screen utility already has too many customization scope via the commands it offers. I think that I'm not able to exploit it just. Would love to see the config files approach.

Comment: here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418537/shell-script-start-1-session-with-multiple-windows

Answer (score -2):

This is very nice, but maybe you should invest some time in discovering how to run system scripts via init (and the like) instead. `screen` is made primarily for human consumption.

Comment: Ive thought about what you have written here.

its simply not true, and not really in the spirit of stackoverflow

There are some scenarios where init Sys5 or SystemD scripts are what is wanted, and some where it is not. If you wanted to suggest that as an alternative, you could have done just that :)